# How does JPA map a column name to a field if the column name is different than the field name?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have a table `Students` which has columns `varchar firstname` and `varchar lastname`.

For some reason my Entity Class has fields with different names, say `String fname` and `String lname`.

So how does JPA correctly map the column with the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `@Column` annotation, e.g.

```java
@Entity(name="Students")
public class Students {
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String fname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lname;
}
```

Comment: Also how does JPA map differently named columns and fields on its own. Like if the column name is created_date and field name is createdDate, there is no use of the @Column annotation.

Comment: If you don't use the `@Column` annotation, then the column name will be whatever the Java field name is.

Comment: What I meant was, I already have a Table with some columns. How does JPA then map the fields to the already existing columns with different names without @Column.

Comment: I believe JPA won't be able to do the mapping without `@Column` in this case.  I suggest _deleting_ your existing table and instead letting JPA set it up for you.  Then, if you need to, populate it with data outside your Java application.

Comment: Even I thought the same, but in the example I gave in the comments, even without the use of @Column annotation I was able to map the column name created_date to the field name createdDate successfully. That is what I did not understand.